# Xamarin Highlight rows in ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin/Android. I have a listview with around 20 rows (to view the last few rows, users need to scroll down). I have a requirement to automatically highlight random rows based on some calculated values. My question is, once a listview is populated (I have a custom adapter to populate the listview), how can I set the background or foreground color of the row of choice (say 3rd row, highlight it for 10 seconds then highlight 1st row - the row number is based on a calculation).

Can I also autoscroll up/down to display a row which is currently not within the screen real estate? For example, if I am currently highlighting row 2 and next I need to highlight row 15, I want the app to automatically scroll down and display row 15 highlighted. Is it possible?

The below is my custom adapter.

```
public class PeopleListAdapter: BaseAdapter<Content>
    {
        List<Content> content;
        Activity context;
        public PeopleListAdapter(Activity context, List<Content> content) : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.content = content;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override Content this[int position]
        {
            get { return content[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return content.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
            if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listlayout, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtValues).Text = content[position].Text;
            return view;
        }
    }
```

The below listed is my listview layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">

  <ListView
       android:minWidth="25px"
       android:minHeight="25px"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/list" >    
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have the adapter populating the below layout (listlayout.axml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtValues" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest whether I am doing this right. I am new to this. I also would like to know how can I highlight the row of my choice given the above implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In your getview method, you have a view which you are inflating for each row:

```
 View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available

 if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
 view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listlayout, null);
```

Here, assign a tag property to the view. i.e. view.setTag(position).

Then in the same method getview, add a check if(Integer.parserInt(view.getTag()) == positionToHighlight), then set the background colour of the view. eg: view.setBackground()